# Angular project "net::ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: angular

I have build a simple project in angular with auth jwt and all works fine locally, problems appears once I have uploaded my project to Ionos server (PLESK running ubuntu with no firewall). I am going to describe what happens:

- ng build --configuration=production, it builds 'dist' folder

my angular.json

```html
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "portfol2o": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/portfol2o",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets/",
                "output": "/assets/"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/custom-theme.scss",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "1mb",
                  "maximumError": "2mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "200kb",
                  "maximumError": "300kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "optimization": true,
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "portfol2o:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "portfol2o:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "portfol2o:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets/",
                "output": "/assets/"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

- then FTP to Ionos server/subdomain ok
- then ssh to Ionos server/subdomain ok
- npm install express mysql2 cors jsonwebtoken bcryptjs ok
- node app.js ok

  Server started on port 5500

Here its code:

```html
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const mysql = require('mysql2');

// Inicializa la aplicación Express
const app = express();
// Configuración de CORS
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'https://server.ionos.com'
}));
app.use(express.json());

// Configura la conexión a la base de datos MySQL
const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock',
  user: 'portfol2odbuser', // Reemplaza con tu usuario de MySQL
  password: 'passdb', // Reemplaza con tu contraseña de MySQL
  database: 'portfol2odb', // Reemplaza con tu base de datos de MySQL
  connectionLimit: 10 // Número máximo de conexiones simultáneas
});

// Ruta de registro
app.post('/auth/register', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Registrando usuario...');
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;

  if (!email || !password) {
    return res.status(400).send('Username and password are required');
  }

  const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
  const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);

  const query = 'INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
  const values = [name, email, hashedPassword];

  console.log('Query:', query, 'Values:', values); // Agrega este console.log

  pool.query('INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [name,email, hashedPassword], (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      if (error.code === 'ER_DUP_ENTRY') {
        res.status(400).send('Email already registered');
      } else {
        res.status(500).send(`An error occurred during registration: ${error.sqlMessage}`);
      }
    } else {
      res.status(200).json({ message: 'User registered successfully' });

    }
  });
});

// Ruta de inicio de sesión
app.post('/auth/login', (req, res) => {

  const { email, password } = req.body;
  console.log(req.body);
  if (!email || !password) {
    return res.status(400).send('Username and password are required');
  }

  pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], (error, results) => {
    if (error || results.length === 0) {
      res.status(400).send('Invalid credentials1');
    } else {
      const user = results[0];

      if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
        res.status(400).send('Invalid credentials2');
      } else {
        const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, 'your_secret_key', { expiresIn: '1h' });
        res.status(200).send({ token });
      }
    }
  });
});

// Iniciar el servidor
app.listen(5500, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 5500');
});
```

- then node server.js ok

Server started on port 3300
Connecting to database
Connected to database

Here its code:

```html
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

// Configuración de CORS
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'https://portfol2o.microporfolio.com'
}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  socketPath: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock',
  user: 'portfol2odbuser',
  password: 'passdb',
  database: 'portfol2odb'
});
/*const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '123456',
  database: 'usuarios_datos'
});*/

connection.connect((err) => {
  console.log('Connecting to database');
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Connected to database');
});

app.listen(3300, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 3300');
});
// GET all users
app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM users', (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(results);
  });
});

// GET a user by id
app.get('/users/:id', (req, res) => {
  const {id} = req.params;
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', [id], (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(results[0]);
  });
});

// POST a new user
app.post('/users', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Registrando usuario2...');
  const {name, email, password, ord} = req.body;
  connection.query('INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [name, email, password], (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(results);
  });
});

// PUT an existing user by id
app.put('/users/:id', (req, res) => {
  const {id} = req.params;
  const {name, email, password} = req.body;
  connection.query('UPDATE users SET name = ?, email = ?, password = ? WHERE id = ?', [name, email, password, id], (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(results);
  });
});

// DELETE a user by id
app.delete('/users/:id', (req, res) => {
  const {id} = req.params;
  connection.query('DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ?', [id], (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(results);
  });
});

// GET all articles
app.get('/articles', (req, res) => {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM articles', (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(results);
  });
});

// GET an article by id
app.get('/articles/:id', (req, res) => {
  const {id} = req.params;
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = ?', [id], (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(results[0]);
  });
});

// POST a new article
app.post('/articles', (req, res) => {
  const {title, content, user_id} = req.body;
  connection.query('INSERT INTO articles (title, content, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [title, content, user_id], (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(results);
  });
});

// PUT an existing article by id
app.put('/articles/:id', (req, res) => {
  const {id} = req.params;
  const {title, content, user_id} = req.body;
  connection.query('UPDATE articles SET title = ?, content = ?, user_id = ? WHERE id = ?', [title, content, user_id, id], (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(results);
  });
});

// DELETE an article by id
app.delete('/articles/:id', (req, res) => {
  const {id} = req.params;
  connection.query('DELETE FROM articles WHERE id = ?', [id], (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(results);
  });
});
```

probing my webservices apis

> root@silly-driscoll:~# curl -X GET http://localhost:3300/articles
> [{"id":1,"title":"Articulo de prueba unico","content":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris suscipit tortor sed sem sagittis, ut egestas neque consequat. Aenean non ornare arcu, et volutpat enim. ","user_id":1}]
> root@silly-driscoll:~#

- the I access to this endpoint https://server.ionos.com/articles

but console gives me http://localhost:3300/articles net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED all the time, I do not know what else to do, I have tried so many things. Little bit tired now.

Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

for those in the same case, you can fix it simply open desired port over firewall on server. That was the cause I cannot comunnicate with that port, to be more especific under ubuntu + plesk you have to go to firewall panel (IONOS firewall panel, NOT plesk firewall) and open port there.

I hope it helps.

Best Regards.